# change div into html server control and add an click event

Tags: asp.net, servercontrols

I have a piece of code

```
<div class="class1">
 <span>testing</span>
</div>
```

I will change this into html server control.

```
<div class="class1" id="div1" runat="server">
 <span>testing</span>
</div>
```

I want to add a click event.

```
<div class="class1" id="div1" runat="server" onclick="Test_Click">
 <span>testing</span>
</div>
```

On code behind, I have that event handler.

```
protected void Test_Click(object sernder, EventArgs e)
{
  //code
}
```

But it is not working.. I tried by changing `onclick` to `onserverclick`. it is still not working..

Any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your post I got that you want to simple go to the server side event while clicking the Div.
You can't directly give this to a `DIV`, instead you can use a `Hidden Button` in the div and trigger the `click` event `manually`.

```
    <script>
    function clickDiv() {
    if (__doPostBack) {
        __doPostBack('<%=btnNew.UniqueID %>', '');
    }
    else {
        var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
        if (!theForm) {
            theForm = document.aspnetForm;
        }
        if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
            theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = '<%=btnNew.UniqueID %>';
            theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = '';
            theForm.submit();
        }
    }
}
    </script>

<div class="class1" id="div1" runat="server" onclick="clickDiv()">
 <span>testing</span>
<asp:Button runat="server" Style="display: none" ID="btnNew" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnNew_Click" /> 
</div>
```

**In _Default.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            result.Text += "hey, event handler! ";
        }


    }
```

You can see the `jQuery` Implementation over here:
 [JQuery UI Dialog & Asp (web forms) calling event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913189/jquery-ui-dialog-asp-web-forms-calling-event-handler/7913919#7913919)

Comment: Hi, I think your method should work.. But when I implement it, I m having javascript error `Object Expected`

Comment: The above answer is correct but I had to use `document.getElementById('<%=listBtn1.ClientID %>').click();` instead of `dopostback`